# Run C# on google-drive

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, cloud

I am a computer science student , and i was wondering if i can **run a simple c# script**(i dont need any libraries just a main method for example) **on google drive**.

I am trying to do it using https://script.google.com/, but it dont works maybe im configurating it bad.
[image]

the simple code is this, but it can be anyother.

```
class Program {
   
   static void main( ){
     Console.Write("c# script on google drive!");
  } }
```

I dont know if its posible or i have to use google cloud services for this.
Any tutorial , link or help is welcome, Thanks!

Comment: If you can make the app sync locally yes, if not... no

Comment: https://script.google.com is for coding in [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), you might be looking for [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions), you can find the .NET quickstart [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-dotnet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are a little confused by the naming's of the systems  you are trying to use or the capabilities of those systems.

The [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) allows you to create apps that leverage Google Drive cloud storage. You can develop applications that integrate with Google Drive, and create robust functionality in your application using Google Drive API.   It is not going to let you run anything.  Its just file storage.

[Google app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) makes it easy to create and publish add-ons for Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Forms. The language it uses is JavaScript.  That being said this is not the same as calling an app script function from C# using [Execute C#](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#c)

If what you are actually trying to do is run a .net application in Google cloud then i think what you are looking for is [Google cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-dotnet) You can write a google cloud function in .net and run it on Google cloud.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,very helpfull answer!